# Pseudo-class lang in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-class, lang

For an exercise I have to change the size of the french content on my page using the pseudo-class lang in CSS but it is not working.
Here is what I tried.

```
:lang(fr) {
   font-size: 20pt;
     }
```

Comment: please put a complete code. Also tell us if it's for a specifi browser or not

Comment: also read this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp am sure you are missing the attribute in the html

Comment: body{
  margin-top: 100px; 
  text-align: center;  
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  }
:lang(fr) {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
a { 
 color: #b4b4b4; 
} 
:visited {
  color: #3c3c3c
}
img {
    opacity: 0.5; 
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

Comment: Here is the code and it is not for a specific browser

Comment: the code need to go in your question, so edit it ... and i was talking about a complete HTML/CSS code, not only CSS

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add the `lang` attribute to your html:

```
<div lang="fr">
```

Otherwise your css looks correct.

You can read up more about `lang` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang